# Changes disappear if I navigate away from page and comeback to that page - Ionic App

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

In my ionic app, I have a page where the information can be edited and saved. One of the info is the image. To select a new image, it is designed to navigate away to a page containing images to select from.

So, if user changes some other text fields and then try to change the image, he has to navigate away from page to select new image. But once he is back after image selection, all other changes are gone and it is back to old data.

I want other information to persist once user comes back to the page.

Here is my current code :

```
<div class="content content-top content-bottom">
            <ch-device-avatar ng-model="client" ch-size="xxlarge" ch-color="light"
                              ng-click="go(STATES.DEVICES_EDIT_ICON, {'macAddress': macAddress})">
                <ch-avatar ch-icon="ion-edit" ch-size="small" ch-color="positive"></ch-avatar>
            </ch-device-avatar>
        </div>

        <form id="client-form" class="form" name="forms.clientForm" ng-submit="save()" novalidate>
            <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" ch-input-container>
                <span class="input-label">{{ 'main.label-device-name' | i18n }}</span>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="{{ 'main.label-device-name' | i18n }}" autocomplete="off"
                       ng-model="client['name']" ng-maxlength="64" required>
            </label>
            <div ng-messages="forms.clientForm.name.$error" role="alert" ch-messages="name" multiple>
                <div class="hint hint-error" ng-message="required">{{ 'common.error-required' | i18n }}</div>
                <div class="hint hint-error" ng-message="maxlength">{{ 'common.error-max-length' | i18n:'65' }}</div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the components are destroyed once you navigate away from the page.[the default angular behaviour]

You might need to make use of Shared Services to save info on to the service variables so that once you come back you can fetch from them if they are not empty .

You may even go for a real time Database like Firebase for this solution.

Refrence from [Link](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-navigation.html#lifecycle-hooks-and-component-caching)

> With router-outlet new instance of the component is created with
>   each navigation and is destroyed when you navigate to another
>   component. The component's constructor and its init hooks will be
>   called every time you navigate to the component and ngOnDestroy() will
>   be called every time you navigate away from it.

More on Shared Services [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq)